# Callback after attr

Tags: jquery, forms, callback

I'm trying to clear all checkboxes in a form and then submit the form within one function, but the form seems to get submitted before the checkboxes get unchecked. Is there a way to do this with a callback, or is there another way entirely that I should be going about this?

The function looks like this:

```
function clear_checkboxes() {
    $(".addtomailer").attr('checked', false);
    $('#addresses').submit();
    return false;
}
```

The function is called with a form button, .addtomailer is the class for all of the checkboxes, and #addresses is the form ID.

(I did find a lot of questions asking how to do this, but all of the askers were actually trying to test when items were loaded, so the question was never really answered)

UPDATE: Using the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try using `.prop` instead of `.attr`

```
$(".addtomailer").prop('checked', false);
```

in general, use "prop" when the "attribute" is a boolean. (checked, disabled, selected, etc.). "attr" doesn't refresh the element's state properly.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: That depends on the jQuery version used by OP as `prop` was only added in 1.6.2 and OP may not be able to use it.

Comment: I'm adding it as a comment for that reason in-case OP is not using jQuery 1.6.2 or later. It's important information. I suggested this myself in another post and OP used 1.3.2 and was confused not being able to use `prop`.

Comment: jQuery is backwards compatible, upgrading jQuery is a non issue most of the time. Can't understand why there are people still on 1.3.2.

Comment: @elclanrs: Well, until 1.9 when all the methods marked as deprecated will be removed. No more backwards compatibility for `live()` or `trigger()` (for mouse-event) and the likes. It will get even more interesting when 2.0 comes out in the future as it will not support IE6, 7 or 8. As far as it is planned up to now, jQuery 2.0 is not a successor to 1.9 but runs along-side it. We will get many more interesting SO questions then :)

Comment: what ? no ie7/ie8 support :O. I'll add in the traffic.

Comment: I tried using .prop, entirely expecting it to solve my problem because your explanation made complete sense, but I had the same result. When I remove the submit, I see the checkboxes uncheck on click, but when I include the submit code the checkboxes are not visibly unchecked when I click, and after the submit they are still reported as checked. It feels as though the following submit is happening before the unchecking has a chance to happen. I'm unsure about the timing and hierarchy of these things.

Comment: @Imaginary: are you sure something else isn't submitting the form before that function is called? try putting the .submit() on a delay.. `setTimeout(function(){$('#addresses').submit();},2000);` -- see if checkboxes are getting unchecked and if anything else is triggering in that time..

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `checked` attribute from every checkbox and set it value to false.

```
    $(".addtomailer").removeAttr('checked').val(false);
```